# Android Video View issue for higher version

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to view the recorded video in videoview . The functionality workrs fine in android versions below Marshmallow but gives an error in versions above them . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USmu3.png)

Code for the video preview is :

```
private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
        // Checking whether captured media is image or video
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String uriPath =  filePath;
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                UploadActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vidPreview);
        if (CommonMethods.androidVersionCheck() == true) {
            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile((new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath(),uriPath)));
            boolean result = PermissionRequest.checkPermission(this);
            if (result){
                vidPreview.setVideoURI(photoURI);
            }else CommonMethods.AlertTitle("Permission Denied",this);
        }else {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
            vidPreview.setVideoURI(uri);
        }
        vidPreview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        vidPreview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vidPreview.start();
            }
        });
        /*vidPreview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
                return true;
            }
        });*/
    }
```

Log :

```
07-20 16:53:43.133 844-1271/? W/PackageManager: checkUidPermission(): android.permission.STATUS_BAR of 10082 is denied.
07-20 16:53:43.141 24775-24775/com.genexttutors W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /Android_File_Upload/Pictures/Android_File_Upload/VID_20170720_165326.mp4
                                                             java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1113)
                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:998)
                                                                 at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:439)
                                                                 at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:744)
                                                                 at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:709)
                                                                 at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:180)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2553)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
07-20 16:53:43.142 24775-24775/com.genexttutors E/video: setOnErrorListener android.media.MediaPlayer@ff74da6
07-20 16:53:43.148 238-238/? E/MDP: DpBlitStream:: exceed HW limitation, srcWidth 1280, dstWidth 2
```

Comment: Can you post video player code?

Comment: Post your code. Also go to settings and in Apps check whether storage permission has been enabled.

Comment: I have checked for the permission.  Storage permission is already there .

Comment: @Deepti Pednekar- Check carefully whether the file location is added correctly or not. Also make sure your video matches with supported formats  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: @DeeptiPednekar Can you post logs?

Comment: The video is displaying proper in lower version . This issue is only with the higher versions from 7+

Answer (score 0):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

In other words, you need to request permission within the application. AndroidManifest is not enough.

Check for more information and samples:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I provide all the required permissions on runtime.